# Configuring a DNN listener for an availability group fails

Tags: azure, listener

I am running into problem when creating DNN listener on Azure VM.
I am runnign the script provided in Microsoft article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/availability-group-distributed-network-name-dnn-listener-configure?view=azuresql
and getting the following error:
*Set-ClusterResourceDependency :* *An error occurred while setting the dependency relationship for the resource 'myag'.
The operation could not be completed because the cluster resource is online*

[image]

Any help suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the listeners DNS added before running the script then you will get this error. Delete the DNS entries for the listeners and then run the script. Once this finishes then add the static DNS entries.

Hope That helps.

AG